# The progress indicator keeps going after task success... how can i stop it?

Tags: java, javafx

When clicking a button i start a task to authenticate the user and then if the user is authenticated it will run another task to get the user current open shift.

I binded a progress indicator to this task ... but the problem is that the indicator doesn't stop after the task succeeds.

## Update 1

What i'm trying to do is to run the getUserShift Task only if the user is authenticated (authenticate returns a User not null)

So what is the problem here:

```
@FXML
private void signInAction(ActionEvent event) {
    String username = userNameText.getText();
    String password = passwordText.getText();

    Task<Void> runSignInTask = signInTask();
    runSignInTask.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
        System.out.println("SignIn Task Succeeded");
        progressIndicator.progressProperty().unbind();
    });
    runSignInTask.setOnFailed(e -> {
        System.out.println("SignIn Task Failed??!!");
    });
    progressIndicator.progressProperty().bind(runSignInTask.progressProperty());
    new Thread(runSignInTask).start();
}

public Task<Void> signInTask() {
    return new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            Task<User> runAuthTask = authenticate();
            runAuthTask.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
                System.out.println("Task Succeded!!");
                //Check if user Authenticated
                if (runAuthTask.getValue() != null) {
                    System.out.println("Access permitted");
                    //Run the second Task
                    Task<Shift> runGetUserShift = getUserShift(runAuthTask.getValue());
                    runGetUserShift.setOnSucceeded(l -> {
                        System.out.println("getUserShift task succeeded");
                        if (runGetUserShift.getValue() != null) {
                            Shift shift = runGetUserShift.getValue();
                            System.out.println("User has open shift");
                        }
                    });
                    runGetUserShift.setOnFailed(l -> {
                        System.out.println("getUserShift task Failed");
                    });
                    new Thread(runGetUserShift).start();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Access Denied!!");
                }
            });
            runAuthTask.setOnFailed(e -> {
                System.out.println("Task Failed!!");
            });
            new Thread(runAuthTask).start();
            return null;
        }
    };
}

public Task<User> authenticate() {
    return new Task<User>() {
        @Override
        protected User call() throws Exception {
            return Authenticator.authenticated(userNameText.getText(), passwordText.getText());
        }
    };
}

public Task<Shift> getUserShift(User user) {
    return new Task<Shift>() {
        @Override
        protected Shift call() throws Exception {
            return ShiftDAO.getShift(user.getUserId(), user.getBranchId(), user.getComId());
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Why do you run a thread with a JavaFX task within another JavaFx task?

Comment: Your `signInTask` is going to move to `SUCCEEDED` state immediately anyway; all it does is start a new thread in the background.

Comment: @fireandfuel well i thought if i did this they will all run in the same task

Comment: @James_D Ok i updated the question hopefully it'll clarify what i'm trying to accomplish ... what is the correct way to achieve this then?

Comment: @Gado If you want the "indeterminate progress" animation to stop as soon as the `runSignInTask` succeeds, just put `progressIndicator.setProgress(1)` immediately after `progressIndicator.progressProperty().unbind()`. But my point is that the `runSignInTask` doesn't do anything that takes any noticeable time at all, so it would immediately go to that state. It's not at all clear why you are separating this logic into independent tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an application design error why your progressIndicator doesn't stop after the sign in process is done.

I recommend you using a single task to do all your work to sign the user in.
Your sign in task might look like this:

```
public Task<Void> signInTask() {
    return new Task<Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {

            User user = Authenticator.authenticated(userNameText.getText(), passwordText.getText());
            if(user != null){
                 Shift shift = ShiftDAO.getShift(user.getUserId(), user.getBranchId(), user.getComId());
                 if(shift != null){
                     // logic if user has a shift
                 } else {
                     // logic if user has no shift, throw exception, etc.
                 }
            } else {
                 // logic if user is not authenticated, throw exception, etc.
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Please also refer to [Concurrency in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm) and [JavaDoc - Task](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) for further information.

Comment: You might want to add `updateProgress(100, 100);` at the end of the `call()` method, so that it does what the OP wants it to do. And you need `return null ;`, of course.

Comment: @James_D yeah, I completely forgot ``return null;``. ``updateProgress(100, 100);`` is optional.

Comment: If you don't set the progress in the task, it will remain at "indeterminate", so the animation will continue after the task completes (or you can unbind and set the progress indicator's progress; but you need one of these).

Comment: @James_D return null don't fix it ... Unbinding it doesn't work but setting the progress and hiding it in the onSuccess works ... Only with fireandfuel answer ... my code hides it right away ... actually hiding is convenient for an indeterminate progress bar ... it all makes sense to me now ... Thank you guys.